# Use CSS wildcard as a parameter

Tags: css, parameter-passing

I am trying to define a dynamic CSS rule that uses a wildcard as a parameter. Specifically, I want to write this in my HTML:

```
<span class="w-50">one</span>
<span class="w-85">two</span>
<span class="w-110">three</span>
```

And this in my CSS:

```
span[class*='w-'] {
  width: <somehow use the wildcard here>px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And I want this to assign dynamically widths of: 50px, 85px and 110px respectively.

Is it possible to define **one CSS rule** for multiple widths

Comment: Yes but what you want to do is possible via the style attribute and CSS variable :  ex https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NWWQWVa calc is used so you can change the unit value )  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties If that answers your question , you may ask to reopen your question.

Comment: @G-Cyr In this case, simply writing the width inline would be better as we will avoid using calc(), CSS variables and we will have less of code and better support.

Comment: @TemaniAfif calc() is for the demo of the use of --var to give it a bit more interest ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr btw, you can post your answer in the target as even if such solution is acceptable it would belong there. I don't think we should reopen this one since both question are identical.